# Inject Ember service from subfolder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My current ember project is structured like this:

```
+-- app
| services 
|   +-- service1.js
|   |   subfolder
|   |   +-- service2.js
```

I have a service (service1.js) just in the root of the services folder. I can perfectly inject that into a controller like this:

```
    service: Ember.inject.service("service1"),
```

But I want some more structure in my services folder. I want to put a service (service2.js) in a subfolder ('subfolder').

How do I inject this into my controller.js/component.js? If I write down:

```
service: Ember.inject.service("subfolder/service2") or
service: Ember.inject.service("subfolder.service2"),
```

This doesn't work

> Attempting to inject an unknown injection

How can I inject a service from a subfolder into my controller/component/etc ?

Comment: This should work `Ember.inject.service("subfolder/service2")` but you should have `service2.js` inside `subfolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. Here is the [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/86890c9b03e55a59eadaf7b31a1b626b?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

services/subfolder/service2.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  name:'kumkanillam'
});
```

Inject service in the controller `myService:Ember.inject.service('subfolder/service2'),`. You can use it inside application.hbs like `{{myService.name}}`

Comment: I must have misplaced something without noticing. It works now with the subfolder. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

And in 2021 these days with ember.js Glimmer/Octane:

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
export default class UserPlannerBasketOnlyController extends Controller {
     @service('tkc/rangemappings-tkc') rangemappings;
}
```